# How to send phone Number in web service and receive request in android

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I am facing trouble in send data to post method via http client.I want to send any phone number to web service and receive request.

Here my SignUp.java:-

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tv;
Button sign_up;
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    sign_up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_buttton);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_up_editText);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    sign_up.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v){

    validateForm();

/*     if(et.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Please Fill Contect Nuumber",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        postSignUpData();
    }*/
}

public void postSignUpData(){
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

}
private static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String mobile) {
    String regEx = "^[0-9]{10}$";
    return mobile.matches(regEx);
}
private void  validateForm(){
    String mobile = et.getText().toString();

    if(isValidPhoneNumber(mobile)){
        requestForSMS();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Please enter valid mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void requestForSMS(){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/registertele&key=test123$");
    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number",et.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(status==200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Value of json object"+jsonObject,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"GO to else",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    //    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Str value "+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }catch (IOException |JSONException e){
        Log.e("Error :",e.getMessage() );
    }
}
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

}

[Here is a url for my web service](http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/registertele&key=test123$)

Here my Logcat:-

```
   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
10-16 15:02:08.189 7560-7560/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
10-16 15:02:08.189 7560-7560/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
10-16 15:02:08.189 7560-7560/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
10-16 15:02:08.189 7560-7560/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)

    E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.SignUp.requestForSMS(SignUp.java:102)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.SignUp.validateForm(SignUp.java:86)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout.SignUp.onClick(SignUp.java:63)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 14:24:44.827 7739-7739/shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.dynamiclayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

I am new in advance android.Please Help.Thanks is advance

Comment: any errors you are facing ?

Comment: i post my error see my edited question

Comment: There will some exception mentioned in your logcat post that too, above the first line,

Comment: see my edited question

Comment: It is because you are doing `NetworkCall` in the main thread, use `AsyncTask` or `Handler` to post the data to your webservice

Comment: Thanks @ Satyen Udeshi you solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its not problem with your code .You are using min api level 2.3 etc.So in that you need to do network operations in asynctask or use following code before your code to avoid exception

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 }
```